Encountered file missing or invalid when debugging xv6 source code in Visual Studio Code
I have been able to debug my xv6 code using riscv64-unkown-elf-gdb in the macOS terminal, specifically I need to do this:
In one terminal:
seohyun@souseohyundeMacBook-Pro ~ % cd ~/Development/xv6-lab
seohyun@souseohyundeMacBook-Pro xv6-lab % make qemu-gdb
*** Now run 'gdb' in another window.
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel
 -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -global virtio-mmio.force-legacy=false -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,
bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0 -S -gdb tcp::25501


As it says, in another terminal window:
seohyun@souseohyundeMacBook-Pro ~ % riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb ~/Development/xv6-lab/kernel/kernel
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3.0.20190516-git

xxxxxxxxx(Omitting some gdb startup print messages)

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /Users/seohyun/Development/xv6-lab/kernel/kernel...
(gdb) 

I'm a rookie programmer, and simply using gdb to debug in the terminal seriously reduces my efficiency, so I'm going to configure VSCode for debugging XV6 code.
launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug xv6",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/kernel/kernel",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:25501",
            "miDebuggerPath": "riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "xv6-build",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                //在这里加载了寄存器信息表
                {
                    "text": "set tdesc filename Debug.xml",
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}

tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "xv6-build",
            "type": "shell",
            "isBackground": true,
            "command": "make qemu-gdb",
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "pattern": [
                        {
                            "regexp": ".",
                            "file": 1,
                            "location": 2,
                            "message": 3
                        }
                    ],
                    "background": {
                        "beginsPattern": ".*Now run 'gdb' in another window.",
                        // 要对应编译成功后,一句echo的内容. 此处对应 Makefile Line:170
                        "endsPattern": "."
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

When I started debugging on VSCode, XV6 ran normally in qemu and it recognized riscv-unkown-elf-gdb and started normally:

 *  正在执行任务: make qemu-gdb 

*** Now run 'gdb' in another window.
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -global virtio-mmio.force-legacy=false -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0 -S -gdb tcp::25501

xv6 kernel is booting

hart 1 starting
hart 2 starting
init: starting sh
$ 

But VSCode pops up a window to report an error:
Unable to start debugging. Program path '/Users/seohyun/Development/xv6-lab/kernel/kernel' is missing or invalid.

GDB failed with message: Architecture of file not recognized.

This may occur if the process's executable was changed after the process was started, such as when installing an update. Try re-launching the application or restarting the machine.

I really don't understand why the program kernel is missing or invalid.
Obviously they work fine at the command line.
I've added some additional commands to try to illustrate the message:
seohyun@souseohyundeMacBook-Pro xv6-lab % ls -l /Users/seohyun/Development/xv6-lab/kernel/kernel

-rwxr-xr-x  1 seohyun  staff  270720  8 21 05:13 /Users/seohyun/Development/xv6-lab/kernel/kernel

seohyun@souseohyundeMacBook-Pro xv6-lab % file /Users/seohyun/Development/xv6-lab/kernel/kernel

/Users/seohyun/Development/xv6-lab/kernel/kernel: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, UCB RISC-V, RVC, double-float ABI, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped

Running：

Apple M3 Pro
macOS 14.5 (23F79)
Xcode CLT 15.1

Looking forward to everyone's responses
